# How to use ShimmerFrameLayout with ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put an ImageView inside a ShimmerFrameLayout, however I do not want the ShimmerFrameLayout to affect the alpha or color of the ImageView. Currently, I am creating my ShimmerFrameLayout like this:

```
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout = new ShimmerFrameLayout(this);
    shimmerFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder builder = new Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder();
    builder.setBaseAlpha(0.7f);
    builder.setHighlightAlpha(1.0f);
    builder.setRepeatCount(0);
    shimmerFrameLayout.setShimmer(builder.build());
```

I am then adding my ImageView like this:

```
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    ShimmerFrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ShimmerFrameLayout.LayoutParams(ShimmerFrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ShimmerFrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 10;
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 10;
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 25;
    layoutParams.topMargin = 25;
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This works fine but it sets the alpha of my ImageView to 0.7f. The desired effect that I am trying to achieve is my ImageView at full alpha and the white shimmer effect to still be visible. I cannot set baseAlpha to 1.0f and highlightAlpha to 1.0f as this results in no shimmer showing at all.

I have tried using Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder and setting the highlightColor to white but this doesnt work as it just draws whatever color is set inside builder.setBaseColor() over the top of my ImageView and the ImageView is not visible at all. Setting builder.setBaseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) just sets the base color to black.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Image inside SimmerLayout?

Comment: yes I am doing shimmerFrameLayout.addView(imageView);

Comment: Don't do this because shimmer's alpha affects all its children. Make a layout that contains 2 views and places ImageView overlay your shimmer

Comment: But if the ImageView overlays the ShimmerLayout then I won't be able to see the shimmer right?

Comment: It just covers the area the same as its size. The shimmer below still ok

Comment: did you find a way to solve this?